# How to change image in activity from fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity, android-button

In an android app I have an activity with several fragments. In one of these fragments I have an `ImageButton`. On click I want to let something happen in the activity directly, not in the fragment. In this case I want to set an image. Summed up, the `ImageButton` is in the fragment, but the `ImageView` I want to change on click is in the activity.

How do I achieve that? Whatever I've tried resulted in an app crash.

This is how my fragment.kt looks:

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

companion object{
    fun newInstance() = Fragment1()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    imageButton.setOnClickListener{
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.example)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

var callbacks: OnFragmentCallbacks? = null

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    callbacks = activity as OnFragmentCallbacks
}

interface OnFragmentCallbacks{
    fun changeImage(resourceId: Int)
}

companion object{
    fun newInstance() = Fragment1()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    imageButton.setOnClickListener{
        callbacks?.changeImage(R.drawable.example)
    }
}
```

**In your Activity:**

```
// Change FragmentName with name of your Fragment class
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FragmentName.OnFragmentCallbacks{

override fun changeImage(resouseId: Int){
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resourceId))
    // or
    imageView.setImageResource(resourceId)
}
```

**Just coded it in stackoverflow, may not be perfect**

Comment: Thank you sir! It worked liked a charm after removing the question mark from `(context: Context?)`

Comment: which one worked? imageView.setImageResource(resourceId) or first one?

Comment: Both works, but I'd recommend `imageView.setImageResource(resourceId)` because when using the other option android studio complains about the syntax.